# How to install PostGIS into Postgres-XL correctly?

Tags: postgis, geos, postgres-xl

I have Postgres-XL 10 installed with geos-3.9.1 and postgis-3.1.1 on my Amazon Linux 2 machine. My cluster is running and working flawlessly but I am having troubles with getting postgis installed into the database. I've built and installed everything from source.

The error I'm getting when I run `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` is:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/local/pgsql/lib/postgis-3.so": libgeos_c.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Using solutions from other posts online, I have tried:

- Running `sudo ldconfig`
- Using the `--enable-shared` option when installing geos and postgis
- Ensured `/usr/local/lib` is in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable and I also added `/usr/local/pgsql/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

None of these solutions worked. I can't install PostGIS or Geos using yum because it will install postgresql 12 which conflicts with my version of postgresql which is a custom one for Postgres-XL.

Is there anything else I can try to solve this error? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might need to downgrade.   Postgres-XL is only supporting 2.0.x versions of postgis right now.   At least according to their docs.

https://www.postgres-xl.org/faq/

> ```
> Q. Is PostGIS supported?
> Yes, PostGIS can be added to Postgres-XL. It has been tested with PostGIS 2.0.
> ```